# Handling application wide commands

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm doing some research on WPF and MVVM to evaluate if this is something we wish to implement in a project.

There is one particular thing that I quite cannot understand (my book on WPF hasn't arrived yet).

I've read Josh Smith's article 'WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern' and also his article 'Using RoutedCommands with a ViewModel in WPF'.

My demo application is somewhat different from Josh Smith's demo in that I have menu items that aren't directly bound to the main view model, but would rather be handled by other view-models.

My main window is bound to a MainViewModel object which exposes a object called View (derived from a ViewModelBase class and bound to the Main Window through a ContentControl). This View object is replaced with different ViewModel's such as CustomerViewModel, CustomersViewModel etc. (these are rendered using views defined in my resource dictionary: ).

All this is well and find, but since I wan't menu items in my main window (such as New, Save etc.) that should be enabled, disabled based on the view I found Josh Smith's article on the CommandSink pattern(?) but he states that it is obsolete, and one should rather use the RelayCommand.

Now I am confused, as I cannot figure out how to implement this functionality using this approach.

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to have each view expose a property of type `MenuItem`, which contains its local menu.  (The menu itself can live in the view's resource dictionary; you just implement a property getter that retrieves it using `FindResource`.)

Then make your main menu look something like this:

```
<Menu>
   <MenuItem Header="File">
      <!-- content for your application's File menu goes here -->
   </MenuItem>
   <MenuItem Header="Edit">
      <!-- content for your application's Edit menu goes here -->
   </MenuItem>
   <MenuItem Header="{Binding SelectedView.MenuItem.Header}"
             ItemsSource={Binding SelectedView.MenuItem.Items}/>
   <MenuItem Header="Help">
      <!-- content for your application's Help menu goes here -->
   </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

**Edit**

I think I misunderstood your question, but in part that's because I think your question's much easier to answer than the one I thought you were asking.

Create a `RoutedCommand` property in your application view model called `DisabledCommand` that is always disabled.  Then bind your application menus to commands like this:

```
public RoutedCommand SaveCustomerCommand
{
    get
    {
       CustomerView cv = SelectedView as CustomerView;
       return cv == null
          ? DisabledCommand;
          : ((CustomerViewModel)cv.DataContext).SaveCommand;
    }
}
```

The casting is a little awkward looking, but other than that this is straightforward, elegant even.  The only implementation detail your application view needs to know about the customer view is that there's a `SaveCommand` on its view model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is close to how I do it with commands that are tightly coupled with the currently active view, and your example here is how I figured the RelayCommand should be used. It does not 'disable' commands the view doesn't handle though, which is my goal - but rather lists up every command the view CAN handle.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The approach you're describing is much like the way I do it in my WinForms application. It gives much more control of the menu system. I guess I assumed all this could be solved using XAML :)

Comment: Hi again. I'm trying to make a good solution, and I'm not sure I'm there yet. In your code sample, you check for a CustomerView. You probably mean CustomerViewModel, but that is besides the point. This approach requires a cast to every ViewModel that should support the Save command. Currently I'm trying to make this work using a CommandSink (Josh Smith), but I'm unsure since it's 'obsolete'...

Comment: If you're going to have multiple view models that all implement save commands, you should define an interface that exposes a `SaveCommand` property.  Then that first line can be `IHasSaveCommand vm = SelectedView as IHasSaveCommand`.  Just don't call it `ICanHasSaveCommand`, I beg of you.